# Parse re-registers device on re-install of app

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-notifications

I am trying to register my device using the following code :

```
private void initParsePushMessaging() {
    Parse.initialize(this, Utils.ParseApplicationID, Utils.ParseClientKey);
    ParseInstallation parseInstallation = ParseInstallation
            .getCurrentInstallation();
    String  android_id = Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);   

    if (ParseUser.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        parseInstallation.put("user",ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
        parseInstallation.put("UniqueId",android_id);
    }
    if (parseInstallation.getObjectId() != null)
        parseInstallation.saveInBackground(); 
    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
}
```

After running this code, I see deviceToken in the Parse website.

The Problem - if I uninstall and reinstall the app on the same device, the same device is registered second time on the same device.

I looked around and found tips to include Android_ID etc. which I put in my code. But it hasn't worked.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: see https://www.parse.com/questions/check-for-duplicate-installations-of-same-user-on-re-installation-of-app

Comment: sucks that the sample code is all javascript and some of the calls as Parse.Cloud....  aren't even there in Java. It's ParseCloud here.. I wish they post some proper Java code. I am not sure I like Parse at this point. seems like on proper documentation.

Comment: the idea is to make a query to look for a user with your device id, and to create new one only if there is none yet.